# Coroutines started with asyncio.create_task not running when followed by time.sleep - Why?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm facing an issue with coroutines in Python's asyncio module. I've noticed that coroutines started with asyncio.create_task seem to not run as expected when I introduce a time.sleep immediately after starting them. I'm puzzled by this behavior and would appreciate some insights into why this might be happening.

Here's a simplified example of the code structure:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def my_coroutine():
    # ... coroutine logic ...

# Some function (which I NEED to be non-async)
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(my_coroutine())

    # Introducing time.sleep seems to affect coroutine execution
    while not_ready():
      time.sleep(0.1)  # If this line is removed, the coroutine runs as expected



main()
```

Can an event loop run on multiple threads? if so, how is it possible?

Comment: Use `asyncio.sleep()`.  With `time.sleep()`, the coroutine is still "running", but just happens to be doing nothing.  `asyncio.sleep()` says to let some other coroutine run.

Comment: Can't... I'm trying to build something synchronously/blocking (An Injector binding).
If I try to use async.run, it complains about running nested runs.

Comment: You can't use `asyncio.sleep` in `main` (as written) because `main` isn't an `async` function. Restructure your code so that your wait loop resides in an `async` coroutine.

Answer (score 3):

Assynchronous programming is not multi-threaded programming.
In short: a single thread runs at once, and concurrent tasks or any other code can only run when one does pass the control explicitly to the asynchronous loop.

This can *only* happen by using one of `await`, `async for` or `async with` statements - for any other code, async code just run linearly, in order, and gives no chance for any other asynchronous concurrent code to run.

Thus, calling `time.sleep` in an async function just pause the whole execution, including the loop which is responsible for switching tasks.
The "way" to introduce deliberate pauses in asynchronous code which will allow other tasks to run is to *await* for a call to `asyncio.sleep` instead:

```
# Main function
async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(my_coroutine())

    while not_ready():
      await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # If this line is removed, the coroutine runs as expected

asyncio.run(main())
```

Your example snippet had another problem in that you are trying to create tasks from synchronous code, with no running loop, and never do create or pass control to a loop. That would not work anyway. Your statement of "removing this line makes things work" is just plain incorrect: Python would just yield a "RuntimeError: no running event loop", when you call `asyncio.create_task` in that example.

Maybe you just want to use multithreading instead of async code? Since you give no examples of what your tasks are, if they are not using any of the async features either, it may be simpler to just create new threads, or use a thread-pool, and go with it.

That said, code *can* be written so that a synchronous, "normal", thread can post asynchronous tasks to be executed in another thread running an async event loop. There are examples of that around, and since your own snippets or questions do not demonstrate that is what you are looking for, I won't post yet another example here. The normal workflow would be to have the "main" function spawning the worker tasks be itself asynchronous, just like in the snippet I posted above.

Comment: How can I say that you mentioned... having a loop in another thread? or even better... is it possible to have a loop that picks from a pool of threads to execute tasks?